# wordpress Redirect after password reset

Tags: wordpress, redirect, passwords

I want users to be redirected to the home page after going through the password reset process.  Current process is as follows:

1. Click Lost Password.
2. Enter username or email and click "Get New Password".
3. User gets email with link to reset password.
4. User clicks link and get password reset page.
5. User enters new password and clicks "Reset Password".
6. The user is sent to a login page.
7. The enter the username and password and click "Log In".

This is where I want them to be directed to the home page. Instead they are directed to a profile edit page.

I have installed Theme My Login and Peter's Login Redirect".  I still end up at the profile edit page.  Which I don't want them to ever go to anyway.  I will be adding a custom profile edit page to the front end a little later.

Thanks for any help anyone can provide.

Comment: In `Theme My Login` you can do that easily and don't need the other plugin. ¿What's the problem then?

Comment: This might help you:

http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/82955/wordpress-redirect-after-password-reset

Best regards,
Eek

Answer (score -2):

You don't need to add plugins for the re-directions just add the           `wp_redirect(home_url();`
where you are submitting your action:

```
if( isset( $_POST['posteddata'] )){
    wp_redirect( home_url('/whatever_your_page')) );
    blablabla;
}
```